# PHP generating PDF for download with an empty line at the beginning of the file

Tags: php, pdf

I am serving a PDF file for download via PHP.

It happens that the downloaded file is appearing with an empty line at the beginning of the file.

I only discovered this because an user could not open the file in Windows. In Linux, the PDF can be opened without any problems.

The original PDF file in the server is without this empty line... and can be normally opened by the Microsoft user.

This is the PHP code I am using:

```
$f=fopen($filepath,'rb');
#$f=fread($f,filesize($filepath));
if($f){
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filepath));
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$c_file.'"');
    #fpassthru($f);
    while(!feof($f)){
        $buffer=fread($f,2048);
        print $buffer;
    }
    fclose($f);
}else die('Ops!');
```

Here's the beginning of the downloaded PDF file:

```
- - -

%PDF-1.4
%Çì¢
7 0 obj
<</Length 8 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
- - -
```

Comment: You probably have some white space before the `<?php` tag (or after the `?>` tag in some included file).

Comment: Try `ob_flush();` before headers.

Comment: @Rikesh: I got "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent..." and the PDF's content was printed in the browser screen instead of downloaded...

Comment: @Álvaro: isn't there a way to use `trim` to avoid this empty line?

Comment: @Álvaro: it looks you were right. Thanks / gracias / obrigado !

Comment: @Roger - Just fix it. It's so trivial to fix that there's no benefit in using workarounds—other developers (including yourself in the future) will see the leading white space and start wondering "why doesn't it get printed"?.